# Classification using categorical input data and image input data

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, classification

I have a tiny dataset of around 300 rows. Each row has:
Column A: An image,
Column B: Categorical text input,
Column C: Categorical text input,
Column D: Categorical text output

I am able to use a sequential Keras model on the image input data alone (Column A) to predict the output (Column D), but the accuracy is pretty abysmal (around 40%). How can I combine the image data with the categorical input data(s) to obtain better accuracy?

Following is the code I'm using. I get the error on model.fit:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'item1'

There are no numbers in the data I am using, everything is categorical text. I think there is something I need to change in the models for the 'y' so it knows that the prediction is to be categorical and not numeric. I'm not sure what to change though.

```
drive.mount('/content/gdrive/')
train = pd.read_csv(r'gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Fast AI/testfilled.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(train)
df = df[['Column A', 'Column B', 'Column C', 'Column D']]

def process_categorical_attributes(df, train, test):
  zipBinarizer = LabelBinarizer().fit(df["Column B"])
  trainCategorical = zipBinarizer.transform(train["Column B"])
  testCategorical = zipBinarizer.transform(test["Column B"])

  zipBinarizer2 = LabelBinarizer().fit(df["Column C"])
  trainCategorical2 = zipBinarizer.transform(train["Column C"])
  testCategorical2 = zipBinarizer.transform(test["Column C"])

  trainX = np.hstack([trainCategorical, trainCategorical2])
  testX = np.hstack([testCategorical, testCategorical2])
  return (trainX, testX)

def load_piece_images(df):
  train_image = []
  for i in tqdm(range(train.shape[0])):
    img = image.load_img('gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/OutputDir/' + train['FileName'][i] + '.bmp',target_size=(400,400,3))
    img = image.img_to_array(img)
    img = img/255   
    train_image.append(img)
  return np.array(train_image)

def create_mlp(dim, regress=False):  
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=dim, activation="relu"))
  model.add(Dense(4, activation="relu"))
  if regress:
    model.add(Dense(1, activation="linear"))
  return model

def create_cnn(width, height, depth, filters=(16, 32, 64), regress=False):
    inputShape = (height, width, depth)
    chanDim = -1
    inputs = Input(shape=inputShape)
    for (i, f) in enumerate(filters):
        if i == 0:
            x = inputs
        x = Conv2D(f, (3, 3), padding="same")(x)
        x = Activation("relu")(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim)(x)
        x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(16)(x)
    x = Activation("relu")(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim)(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Dense(4)(x)
    x = Activation("relu")(x)
    if regress:
        x = Dense(1, activation="linear")(x)
    model = Model(inputs, x)
    return model

images = load_piece_images(df)
split = train_test_split(df, images, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
(trainAttrX, testAttrX, trainImagesX, testImagesX) = split

trainY = trainAttrX["Column D"]
testY = testAttrX["Column D"]
(trainAttrX, testAttrX) = process_categorical_attributes(df, trainAttrX, testAttrX)

mlp = create_mlp(trainAttrX.shape[1], regress=False)
cnn = create_cnn(400, 400, 3, regress=False)
combinedInput = concatenate([mlp.output, cnn.output])
x = Dense(4, activation="relu")(combinedInput)
x = Dense(1, activation="linear")(x)
x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(inputs=[mlp.input, cnn.input], outputs=x)

opt = Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-3 / 200)
model.compile(loss="mean_absolute_percentage_error", optimizer=opt)
model.fit(
    [trainAttrX, trainImagesX], trainY,
    validation_data=([testAttrX, testImagesX], testY),
    epochs=20, batch_size=2)
```

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial does a great thing at explaining how to use multiple input sources (text + image data): https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/04/keras-multiple-inputs-and-mixed-data/

Essentially this is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did look at this. However, I'm unable to get past two obstacles - 1) This tutorial uses one categorical variable as an input, and I need two. 2) This uses regression to predict a numerical outcome - but I need classification as my output - there are no numerical values involved. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Simple : for the other categorical variable, you declare another input: thus you have input_1, input_2, input_3, exactly like in the tutorial with an additional one. And for the classification output... you add, depending on your problem, Dense(1,activation='sigmoid') or Dense(n_classes, activation = 'softmax')

Comment: That's helpful! I've added my code to the question. I'm now declaring multiple categorical inputs and doing np.hstack over them. This seems to be the right approach, I reckon. However, even after adding Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'), I still get an error on model.fit where it says it could not convert string to float. Could you suggest what I can do to fix this?

Comment: If it solved your initial problem, kindly accept and upvote my answer. You are asking now a different question, which you should normally put in a separate question. As for your last error, ensure that you correctly convert the string to float; if this does not happen it means maybe that you do have some string values which are not numbers (saved as numbers) so the conversion fails.

Comment: Manually ensure that all your data is of numpy + float prior to feeding it to the model.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, there are no numbers in the data I am using, everything is categorical text. I think there is something I need to change in the models for the 'y' so it knows that the prediction is to be categorical and not numeric. I'm not sure what to change though, and hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that is sometimes used (e.g. in conditional GANs and AlphaFold 2) is to encode the categorical data as extra scalar feature channels in the input image. So, for example, if you have the categories 1-hot encoded you would take the vector that looks something like [0, 1, 0, ...] and extend your RGB channels with one channel full of 0's, another full of 1's, another full of 0's, etc.

The advantage over the other approach (concatenating the categorical feature encoding onto the neural embedding) is that the neural network itself sees more features, which in some cases is necessary when the RGB channels don't have enough information to discriminate between classes of interest. The disadvantage is that it is not as computationally or memory efficient.